Why is my fridgeItems not updating and 'items' log not logging? (Look at the newFoodData function)
import React, { Component,useState,useEffect,setState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios'
const userData = {user:{"_id":{"$oid":"661762c58c37eabdfd7c72fb"},"email":"jamessinotte@icloud.com","name":"James","password":"$2a$10$0OBWTlL9MIxge1KpOHt.b.y1q4peFA4LJcZI9vH8rcK1aRzZCXw3y","userNumber":"319290895","recipes":{"name":{"$numberInt":"0"}},"ingredients_use":{"made":false,"ingredients":[]},"ingredients_weight":{"name":{"$numberInt":"0"}},"restrictions":{"diets":[{"text":"Vegan","id":"Vegan","value":true},{"text":"Vegetarian","id":"Vegetarian","value":false},{"text":"Pork free","id":"Pork-free","value":true},{"text":"Pescatarian","id":"Pescatarian","value":false},{"text":"Sugar conscious","id":"Sugar conscious","value":false},{"text":"Kosher","id":"Kosher","value":false},{"text":"No sugar","id":"No-sugar","value":false},{"text":"Keto","id":"Keto","value":false},{"text":"Paleo","id":"Paleo","value":false}],"allergies":[{"text":"Dairy","id":"Dairy-free","value":true},{"text":"Gluten","id":"Gluten-free","value":false},{"text":"Eggs","id":"Eggs-free","value":true},{"text":"Peanuts","id":"Peanut-free","value":false},{"text":"Tree Nuts","id":"Tree-Nut-free","value":true},{"text":"Wheat","id":"Wheat-free","value":true},{"text":"Lupine","id":"Lupine-free","value":false},{"text":"Soy","id":"Soy-free","value":false},{"text":"Shellfish","id":"Shellfish-free","value":false}],"made":true},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}}
const userNumber = userData.user.userNumber
class Fridge extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            foodData: [],
            fridgeItems:[],
            made: false,
            selectedValue: null
        }
    }
        newFoodData = async () => { 
        try{ 
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/Food`) 
            const data = await response.json()

            const newItems = data.map(item => ({...item, use:false}))
            console.log(newItems,'items seen')
            const newData = {fridgeItems:newItems}
            this.setState({ fridgeItems: newItems }, () => {
                console.log('items', this.state.fridgeItems);  
            });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('fetch Error',error)
    }
}


        
    componentDidMount = async () => {
        console.log(userData)
        if (userData.user.ingredients_use.ingredients.length == 0){
            this.newFoodData()       }
        else{
            const newItems = userData.user.ingredients_use.ingredients
            const newData = {
                fridgeItems: newItems
            }
            this.setState((prevState) => { return {...prevState,...newData}})
            
        }


        
    }
    updateFoodDataSubmit = async (fridgeItems) => {
        const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/FridgeHome/${userNumber}`,{fridgeItems})

    }
    deleteItem = (index) => {
        const newItems = this.state.fridgeItems.map((type,idx) => {
            if (idx == index)
                return {...type, 'use': !use}

        })
        newData = {fridgeItems:newItems,made:true}
        this.setState((prevState) => { return {...prevState,...newData}})
    }
    
    addFridge = async () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            
            const fridgeItemss = prevState.fridgeItems
            if (this.state[prevState.selectedValue]) {
                const itemToUpdate = {...fridgeItems[prevState.selectedValue]}
                itemToUpdate['use'] = true
                fridgeItems[prevState.selectedValue] = itemToUpdate

            }
        return {...prevState,fridgeItems:fridgeItemss}

        })
           }    
    handleChange = async (e) => {
        this.setState({selectedValue: e.target.value})
    }
    
    render(){
        
        const fridgeList = this.state.fridgeItems.map((type,index)=> (
            <button key ={index} onClick={this.deleteItem(index)}/>))
        
        const dropDown = this.state.fridgeItems.map((type,index) => (
            <option key={index}value={type.name}>{type.name}</option>
            

        ))
        console.log(this.state)
        console.log(dropDown)

        

    return(
        <>
        <h1 id='Welcome_MyFridge'>Welcome to Fridge!</h1>
        <div className='Fridge'>

        </div>
        <div className="Add-Fridge">
            <form>
            <select onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.addFridge}>
                {dropDown}
            </select>
            <button onClick={this.addFridge}></button>
            </form>

        </div>
        </>
    )
}    
}
export default Fridge



For info from the logs, I know the newFoodData() function is called, the newItems is the exact darray I want. However, before the state can update, another component tries to render which requires the fridgeItems array (The deleteItems function is called). I would think that the compenentdidMount() function would fully run/render before fridgeList started to render. Why is this not the case? I tried setting the State through returns but no difference was made.
